# Deployment ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 & Entity Framework Core 1.1 : Unable to load assembly system.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.37.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I migrated my project to ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 and Entity Framework Core 1.1, and all is working fine in develoment.

But impossible to deploy the project in staging, I have this error from stdout logs :

> Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Impossible
>   de charger le fichier ou l'assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' ou
>   une de ses d‚pendances. La d‚finition trouv‚e du manifeste de
>   l'assembly ne correspond pas … la r‚f‚rence de l'assembly. (Exception
>   de HRESULT : 0x80131040) Nom de fichierÿ:
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   … Agata.Presentation.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   --- Fin de la trace de la pile … partir de l'emplacement pr‚c‚dent au niveau duquel l'exception a ‚t‚ lev‚e ---    …
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    …
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    …
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   … Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

I checked all the nuget packages from all the projects contained in the solution and all the dependencies are up to date.

I've deleted all the staging's directory and redeploy it completely to be sure there is no old dlls but the error is still here.
I also restart the IIS pool and the website, several times.

And .NET Core 1.1.0 is installed on the server.

Anyone has an idea on what's going on here ?

EDIT : this is my project.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Npgsql": "3.1.6",
    "Remotion.Linq": "2.1.1",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "System.Interactive.Async": "3.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

**EDIT: The problem is different now, the error now is :**

> Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly
>   'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' ou une de ses d‚pendances. La
>   d‚finition trouv‚e du manifeste de l'assembly ne correspond pas … la
>   r‚f‚rence de l'assembly. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131040)
>       Nom de fichierÿ: 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'
>          … Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddQuery(IServiceCollection
>   serviceCollection)
>          … Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFramework(IServiceCollection
>   serviceCollection)
>          … Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalServiceCollectionExtensions.AddRelational(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>          … Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SqlServerServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>          … Agata.Presentation.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services) dans
>   C:\Workspace\PerformancesEtControles\Agata\DevLot1\Presentation\Agata.Presentation.Web\Startup.cs:ligne
>   65
>       --- Fin de la trace de la pile … partir de l'emplacement pr‚c‚dent au niveau duquel l'exception a ‚t‚ lev‚e ---
>          … System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          … Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>          … Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>          … Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

This is my updated project.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "Npgsql": "3.1.6",
    "Remotion.Linq": "2.1.1",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "System.Interactive.Async": "3.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

The line 65 of my startup file is :

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString")));
```

It's still working fine in debug with visual studio ...

**EDIT 2 :** I resolved the *System.Interactive.Async* updating the *Serilog.Extensions.Logging* package... I have now the error :

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou
>   l'assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.37.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses
>   dépendances. La définition trouvée du manifeste de l'assembly ne
>   correspond pas à la référence de l'assembly. (Exception de HRESULT :
>   0x80131040) Nom de fichier : 'System.Collections.Immutable,
>   Version=1.1.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   à
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorReferenceManager..ctor(ApplicationPartManager
>   partManager, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor)
>   --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---

I'm just going crazy with this deployment ...

**SOLUTION :** deploy the web application executable's configuration file, who contains some class library dependency bindings

Comment: if someone can create the tag 'asp.net-core-1.1' and tag my question, I have no enough reputation to do this. thank's

Comment: Show your Project.json

Comment: You have to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions v 1.0.0 other package have dependencies. Try change it.

Comment: try opening your solution/packages folder and deleting all the packages (leave the repositories.config).  Then right click on your solution in VS and select `restore packages`

Comment: @Adrien: It makes no sense to have a tag for every single minor version, especially not in a fast paced project like ASP.NET Core where every few months a new version is expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to deploy the web application executable's configuration file, who contains some class library dependency bindings. An old practice with .NET is to never deploy a .config file but this practice obviously needs to be reviewed with .NET Core.

When you publish your website, the package generated contains some config file, one of them has the same name as your application's executable, YourWebsiteNamespace.exe.config. This configuration file contains some dll bindings and needs to be deployed with your application

Example of what this file can contain :

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.37.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Metadata" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i @Adrien, could you be more specific ? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Beetlejuice added some info. can you cancel your downvote pls ?

Comment: Where did you get those specific dll versions ?

Comment: The dll who have bindings into this configuration file ? I didn't add them manually, I think they have been added when I updated the version of ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core in my project.json (the content is in my question)

Comment: I never modify this file (webappnamespace.exe.config) and never add System.Collections.Immutable dependency in my project

Comment: Maybe we are publishing in a different way. Here is my way:  sudo dotnet publish -c Release -o /var/www/myapp

Comment: I do not use command line to publish my application. I publish into Visual Studio then paste generated files on the staging server website's directory, excepts settings and configuration files (what was a problem)

Comment: Spent at least 6 hours after upgrading to aspnet core 1.1.  I understand the complexity of system like this but boggle my mind that this doesn't just work out-of-the box :/